# Android View Pager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am working on view pager module in android. I am facing a problem in refreshing the layouts when a particular button is clicked in the viewpager adapter class. My scenario is in this way:
1. I have view with text and image.
2.When image button is clicked, the text should get invisible and image should be shown and vice versa.
Whenever i click on the button, the change takes place on the next screen instead of the current screen. I want the change to be taken place on current screen itself.

If anybody knows how to deal with it, please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working on view pager, if u want to make changes dynamically to the screen at run time for example when you click a button image/text should appear and  vice versa....declare the views inside the onInstantiateItem call back method of View Pager class. The views should be declared with final modifier, then only the changes take place on current screen instead of next screen. Note that, even if u are using variables like int, string etc....everything should be declared inside onInstantiateItem method.
This fixed my problem!!!